# Can I put <style> information into CSS?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if there was a way to shorten my code and put the information in the style component into a CSS file? I am creating a website with a few pages like this and I don't want each page's code to be really long as I am reusing many of the same colours and photos. I have tried to turn it into CSS, however, it seems to just mess my website up.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    body, html {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      font: 400 15px/1.8 "Lato", sans-serif;
      color: #777;
    }

    .bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3 {
      position: relative;
      opacity: 0.65;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;

    }
    .bgimg-1 {
      background-image: url("img_parallax.jpg");
      min-height: 100%;
    }

    .bgimg-2 {
      background-image: url("img_parallax2.jpg");
      min-height: 400px;
    }

    .bgimg-3 {
      background-image: url("img_parallax3.jpg");
      min-height: 400px;
    }

    .caption {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 50%;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      color: #000;
    }

    .caption span.border {
      background-color: #111;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 18px;
      font-size: 25px;
      letter-spacing: 10px;
    }

    h3 {
      letter-spacing: 5px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font: 20px "Lato", sans-serif;
      color: #111;
    }

    /* Turn off parallax scrolling for tablets and phones */
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
      .bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3 {
        background-attachment: scroll;
      }
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="bgimg-1">
      <div class="caption">
      <span class="border">SCROLL DOWN</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div style="color: #777;background-color:white;text-align:center;padding:50px 80px;text-align: justify;">
      <h3 style="text-align:center;">Parallax Demo</h3>
      <p>Parallax scrolling is a web site trend where the background content is moved at a different speed than the foreground content while scrolling. Nascetur per nec posuere turpis, lectus nec libero turpis nunc at, sed posuere mollis ullamcorper libero ante lectus, blandit pellentesque a, magna turpis est sapien duis blandit dignissim. Viverra interdum mi magna mi, morbi sociis. Condimentum dui ipsum consequat morbi, curabitur aliquam pede, nullam vitae eu placerat eget et vehicula. Varius quisque non molestie dolor, nunc nisl dapibus vestibulum at, sodales tincidunt mauris ullamcorper, dapibus pulvinar, in in neque risus odio. Accumsan fringilla vulputate at quibusdam sociis eleifend, aenean maecenas vulputate, non id vehicula lorem mattis, ratione interdum sociis ornare. Suscipit proin magna cras vel, non sit platea sit, maecenas ante augue etiam maecenas, porta porttitor placerat leo.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="bgimg-2">
      <div class="caption">
      <span class="border" style="background-color:transparent;font-size:25px;color: #f7f7f7;">LESS HEIGHT</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div style="position:relative;">
      <div style="color:#ddd;background-color:#282E34;text-align:center;padding:50px 80px;text-align: justify;">
      <p>Scroll up and down to really get the feeling of how Parallax Scrolling works.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bgimg-3">
      <div class="caption">
      <span class="border" style="background-color:transparent;font-size:25px;color: #f7f7f7;">SCROLL UP</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div style="position:relative;">
      <div style="color:#ddd;background-color:#282E34;text-align:center;padding:50px 80px;text-align: justify;">
      <p>Scroll up and down to really get the feeling of how Parallax Scrolling works.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bgimg-1">
      <div class="caption">
      <span class="border">COOL!</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: everything you have in the `style` tag's could be placed inside a css file, and you should link it like this: `<link href="yourcssfilename.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`, the link goes into the `<head>` tag

Comment: Sure you can, just create a .css file, put all your styles in there and call it in all of your pages like this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`

Comment: I just wanted to say the same thing as Ramonde Vries said.

Comment: turning it into css is not a thing by the way, code inside style tags is css code already :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can [put your styles in an external stylesheet](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp). Below is the updated HTML with the external CSS file. Make sure the path to the CSS file is correct (if it's in the same directory, just `style.css`, as below).

HTML File

```
<html>
    <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        </head>

        <body>

        {HTML BODY CONTENT}

        </body>
</html>
```

CSS file (style.css)

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font: 400 15px/1.8 "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #777;
}

.bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3 {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.65;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;

}
.bgimg-1 {
  background-image: url("img_parallax.jpg");
  min-height: 100%;
}

.bgimg-2 {
  background-image: url("img_parallax2.jpg");
  min-height: 400px;
}

.bgimg-3 {
  background-image: url("img_parallax3.jpg");
  min-height: 400px;
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}

.caption span.border {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 18px;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}

h3 {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 20px "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #111;
}

/* Turn off parallax scrolling for tablets and phones */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  .bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3 {
    background-attachment: scroll;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your all css in External.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"> **// External CSS**
<style>
p {
  color: red; **// Internal CSS**
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: lightcyan">  // Inline CSS

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```